# How to enter text at command prompt from shell script without executing command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Is there a way to have a shell script output text at the command prompt **WITHOUT** issuing the command?

**CONTEXT:** I SSH into a particular machine several times a day, and about 80% of the time, I type the same three commands as soon as I login. I would just put these commands in my `.bashrc`, but 20% of the time, I do **NOT** want to issue these commands. I'm wondering if there is some command I can put in `.bashrc` that will automatically put a string at my command line, so that when I login I see:

```
$ cd some/dir && ./some_script.sh
```

I could then just press enter 80% of the time or just clear the text the other 20% of the time.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to log in to enter the commands? Would `ssh user@somehost "cd some/dir && ./some_script.sh"` from your local computer work just as well?

Comment: That's a good idea, but yeah, I do usually want to actually login to the machine as well.

Comment: I would use `expect` for this, but that's just me.

Comment: For what it's worth, the `print` command in `zsh` can do this: `print -z 'cd some/dir && ./some_script.sh'`. I don't think there is a way to execute arbitrary `readline` commands (the relevant ones being `start-kbd-macro`, `end-kbd-macro`, and `call-last-kbd-macro`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Inspired by [Abdul Rehman's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33287887/1126841) answer.)

Put this as the *last* line in your `.bashrc` file:

```
read -e -p "(Control-C to cancel) $ " -i "cd some/dir && ./some_script.sh" && eval "$REPLY"
```

- `read -e` lets you enter a string using Readline for editing.
- The `-p` provides a pseudo-prompt for this one-time command.
- The `-i` provides a default string which you can edit or hit Enter to accept.

If you hit Enter, `read` sets the value of `REPLY` and exits with status 0, causing the following `eval` to execute. (Usually, `eval` is not a good command to use; however, here you would be presented with an interactive shell anyway, so there's not much risk here.) If you type <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> instead, `read` exits with status 1 and the following `eval` is not executed, leaving you at your command prompt.

Comment: Props to all the answers, in particular @shanmuga 's single-character alias. However, this answer came closest to what I originally asked for in that one keystroke allows me to run the command or cancel immediately upon login.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is not what you asked but why don't use `alias` to shorten your command?

```
$ alias a='cd some/dir && ./some_script.sh'
```

Since you are going to use this often you could add this to you .bashrc file, so you don't have to set the alias every time.
After login you could just type `a`

```
$ a
```

Comment: And put the first line in the `.bashrc`. After login you only need to type `a` (and Enter).

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of a way to do that but you *could* use `history -s` to push that command/those commands into the history when you log in which would then let you use `!!<cr>` or `<up><cr>` to execute them and just proceed normally if you don't.

```
history -s cd some/dir '&&' ./some_script.sh
```

You need to quote anything that the shell would normally evaluate/expand/remove. So the `&&` in that example, any quotes, any semicolons, etc.

Comment: This works well as is a big improvement for me (esp. since the real command I want to enter is more complicated). +1 but leaving unchecked for now since I'm curious to see if there's a way to do my initial idea.

Comment: I think you probably meant that someone could hit `<esc>k<cr>` to run the command, because who would use emacs mode? ;)

Comment: @dannysauer People who realize that the shell doesn't have a meaningful "normal mode" since you aren't editing a document and don't generally need to move very far. =)

Comment: I used to think so, but now I can't stand having to hit the arrow keys more than twice. :)  Don't ever switch over to vi mode; it's impossible to go back.

Comment: @dannysauer Why would you use the arrow keys in emacs mode anyway? The modified jumping keys are *much* more useful. ctrl-p for up, alt-b/alt-f for word-jumping, etc.

Comment: Because I already use vi for pretty much everything else and don't have memory to waste learning new commands to do the same things? Emacs mode is for when I don't want to know how to do things. :)

Answer (score 4):

Put this script in .bashrc. It will ask you to run this command.

```
while true; do
read -p "Run this command?" yn
case $yn in
    [Yy]* ) cd some/dir && ./some_script.sh; break;;
    [Nn]* ) break;;
    * ) echo "Enter Yes or No."
esac
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run script on remote server instead loggin via ssh:

```
ssh <SERVER> some/dir/some_script.sh
```

For the remaining 20% you can connect ssh as usual.